# Tensorflow customized embedding not work on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a tensorflow model like following:

```
class EnhancedEmbedding(tf.keras.layers.Embedding):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer='uniform', embeddings_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, embeddings_constraint=None, mask_zero=False, input_length=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer, embeddings_regularizer, activity_regularizer, embeddings_constraint, mask_zero, input_length, **kwargs)
        self.five=tf.constant(0.5)
        self.zero=tf.constant(0)
    
    def embedding(self,inputs):
        return super().call(inputs)
    
    def map_2(self,tokens):
        identifier=self.embedding(tokens[0])
        cur_word=self.embedding(tokens[2])
        return tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(tokens[0]),self.zero),
                lambda: tf.squeeze(cur_word),
                lambda: tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_mean(identifier)*self.five+cur_word*self.five))


    def map_1(self,inputs):
        return tf.map_fn(fn=lambda x :self.map_2(x),elems=inputs,dtype=tf.float32)

    def call(self, inputs):
        final_embeddings=tf.map_fn(fn=lambda x:self.map_1(x),elems=inputs,dtype=tf.float32)

        return final_embeddings
```

```
class EnhancedModel(Model):
    def __init__(self,  embedding_dim, hidden_dim, vocab_size, label_size,seq_len, pretrained_weight):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim
        self.label_size = label_size
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.tanh
        self.num_layers = 1

        self.embedding=EnhancedEmbedding(vocab_size,embedding_dim,embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(pretrained_weight))
        self.encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(hidden_dim, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(seq_len,embedding_dim)))
        self.pool=MaxPool1D(hidden_dim*2)
        self.decoder = Dense(self.label_size)

    def call(self, inputs):
        embeddings = self.embedding(inputs)
        embeddings=tf.reshape(embeddings,[-1,400,32])
        lstm_out = self.encoder(embeddings)
        lstm_out = tf.transpose(lstm_out, perm=[0,2,1])
        pool_out=self.pool(lstm_out)
        out = tf.squeeze(pool_out,[1])
        out = self.decoder(out)
        return out
```

Actually it is a model that cited from others. I only changed the embedding layer and the input.
the input is a RaggedTensor with shape(batch_size,400,3,None), and i use `map_1` and `map_2` function in `EnhancedEmbedding` to general final embedding for the following layers. Everything works fine except that the model is not work with GPU. I looked the GPU utilization using `nvidia-smi` and the result is about 5%. But CPU-Util is about 100%.

I used a virtual conda envs tensorflow=2.3.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 cudnn=7.6.5 Tesla-V100

GPU can be used in the virtual env:

```
>>>tf.test.is_gpu_available()
>>>True
```

I wonder why this happen and how I can fix it?

---

I tried one batch with batch_size=64 on my laptop.The env is: cpu=i7-12700H, tensorflow=2.9.1, cuda=11.6, cudnn=8.4.1.

The code for training is:

```
#both train_x and train_y are list
train_x_enc=tf.ragged.constant(train_x,dtype=tf.int32)
train_y=train_y=tf.convert_to_tensor(train_y,dtype=tf.int32)

with strategy.scope():
    tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(False)
    model = EnhancedModel(EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, MAX_TOKENS, LABELS,SEQ_LEN, pretrain_vectors)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_x_enc,train_y)
```

I find that it take three minute to run a batch for one ecoch. CPU takes long time and GPU only be used(GPU-Util>50%) for several seconds. CPU-Util is about 20% and GPU is about 17% in most of time.

if I changed the code with `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`, I find that the GPU-Util is above 80% all the time with CPU-Util=9%

---

I change the `map_2` of `EnhancedEmbedding` to remove the `tf.cond`:

```
def map_2(self,tokens):
        identifier=self.embedding(tokens[0])
        cur_word=self.embedding(tokens[2])
        return tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_mean(identifier,0)*self.five+cur_word*self.five)
```

However, it still takes about 100s to train for a batch on Tesla-V100, which is almost the same before.

Comment: It is working on the GPU, just that it is less efficient due to the use of branching.

Comment: Can you show the lines where you compile the model and train it? Did the original model (without your modifications) have higher GPU utilization?

Comment: @André I put the code here: [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qdo629GsnIdgbFpqTbIrwOaIHCsfwyJr?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy How can I optimize it without changing the logic?